# accessing and changing module level variable

Tags: python, global

I am studying python from book from Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python. Here global variables and modules are explained as below

keyword 'global' tells python that name should be defined at the outermost scope of the program rather than within the scope of the function.

I have file name circle.py

```
pi = 3.14159

def area(radius):
    return pi * (radius**2)
```

Now at python command line I have following

```
from circle import *

print (pi)
```

output is 3.14159

```
print(area(2))
```

output is 12.56636

Now I defined following

```
global pi
pi = 2

print(pi)
```

output is 2

```
print(area(2))
```

output is 12.56636

I am expecting output to print 8 as i have changed global variable pi to 2.

Is my understanding is correct?

Please correct me I think I am wrong.

Request to help me in understanding the concepts here.

Comment: gloabl variables are local to the file (I think)

Comment: No, altering global variable in your module does not alter a similarly named variable in another module. They are different variables.